# Downloading pdf from ftp is corrupting it

Tags: pdf, ftp, terminal

I am trying to do something very simple. I have a PDF sitting in my root (I'm on a mac). So, first, I want to upload the pdf from the terminal:

```
curl -T myPDF.pdf ftp://user:password@domain.com/
```

then, I download it:

```
ftp name@domain.com
[then it asks for my password, and I type it]
get myPDF.pdf
```

and this downloads the pdf to my local machine. Then, I open up the PDF, and it's corrupted.

So somewhere in the process of uploading it or downloading it, the PDF gets corrupted. Ideas?

Comment: @reising - so you got to a conclusion that it's the download, not the upload?

Answer (score 4):

Transfer it in binary mode instead of ASCII.

```
curl -T myPDF.pdf -Q "TYPE I" ftp://user:password@domain.com/
```

And then for the download, before you type your `get` command, type `binary` to set the ftp client to binary transfer mode.

Comment: and then can I "get" in binary mode?

Comment: Yes, see my update